# Unable to connect to Google Compute Engine using "in browser" SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

After changing two passwords, root and the default user, suddenly we notice now that the "in browser" link on Google Compute Engine fails to connect via SSH.

Strangely, however, if we use the SSH command from the command line that Google provides (i.e. $ gcloud compute ssh VM-NAME --zone VM-ZONE) - SSH works.

It appears SSH is working - but the "in browser" SSH link no longer connects. What might have gone wrong and how do we fix this?

ADDENDUM: 
Of note, a commenter below suggests it is not related to passwords but purely SSH keys - so it looks the answer to this question might rest around if there is a way to regenerate SSH keys on GCE instances. We are searching. If anyone knows code to regenerate SSH keys for GCE please post.

Comment: When you say " GCE admin shortcut SSH "are your referring to ssh through browser ?

Comment: Yes GCE SSH through browser. Question modified.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Per the document you reference, questions are on topic if they refer to software that "involve tools used primarily for programming." [google-cloud] is a development tool with its primary location on StackOverflow. The Unix site mentioned has 22 questions using [google-cloud] as a keyword whereas StackOverflow has over 5,324 questions. Whether google-cloud SSH is done through the Terminal or SSH through Browser utility, this is a question about a tool that is used primarily for programming. The Super User group is for computer enthusiasts or power users. That's not the nature of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered the cause was a **chown** command we had executed on a directory for the primary user that Google creates on the Google Compute Engine instance.

By reversing that chown back to the Google created user, Google's in-browser SSH began working again.

We used chown on an entire user directory and also an ssh config file back to the Google created user using:

```
chown -R user_name_com /home/user_name_com
```

and also on this file

```
chown user_name_com /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

where user_name_com was our gmail email address user.

Comment: I am having the same issue. What directory was it?

Comment: /home/username and /etc/ssh   Just updated the answer with more details. Definitely curious if it works for you.

Comment: This was a little while ago, so my memory is fuzzy. I'm pretty sure I had to type two commands to get it to work for me: `$ gcloud auth login` and `$ gcloud config set project PROJECT`. Then I could SSH in.

Answer (score 1):

GCE VMs, by default, don't allow for SSH connections with clear-text password: it uses keys instead. You can specify approved keys during VM instantiation, or at a later time, but one that is always present is the key to the user account you used when creating the machine.

As long as you haven't modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config, this should continue to be the case. Either way, one more option you can use to connect via SSH to your instance is to run the following command:

$ gcloud compute ssh VM-NAME --zone VM-ZONE

while logged in with your authorized user account.

ADDENDUM - In lieu of regenerating previous keys, you can add additional, locally-generated SSH keys on both the project, as well as on the VM level. The first applies to all VMs and grants access to project owners and editors, while the second only applies to the VM in question. Both methods add the SSH entered to the Metadata server, from which the get uploaded to the VM prior to SSH connection to all / the VM.

You can do this from the Developers Console:

- project-level SSH keys - go to your project -> Compute -> Compute Engine -> Metadata -> "SSH KEYS" (top of the screen) -> click on "Edit"
- VM-level SSH keys - go to your project -> Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances -> click on the instance name -> "SSH keys" section (scroll down) -> click "Add SSH key"

Comment: Thanks Sammy. If it is all keys, then that means nothing we did around passwords affected it. That's helpful to know. We have not *personally* touched sshd_config but perhaps some other process did. Yes we have been using this command and it does work. (That is what I meant by connecting successfully from the command line. I will update the question.)